# Can I use an anonymous type for this Linq grouping?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, anonymous-types

I have the following code which produces a dictionary containing multiple lists; each list can be retrieved with a numeric key.

```
public class myClass
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int GroupIndex { get; set; }
    ...
}

public List<MyClass> myList { get; set; }

private Class IndexedGroup
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetIndexedGroups(string group)
{
    return myList.Where(a => a.Group == group)
                 .GroupBy(n => n.GroupIndex)
                 .Select(g => new IndexedGroup { Index = g.Key, Children = g })
                 .ToDictionary(key => key.Index, value => value.Children);
}
```

*Is there any way to eliminate the `IndexedGroup` class?*

I've tried using an anonymous type in the `Select` method, like this:

```
.Select(g => new { Index = g.Key, Children = g })
```

but I get a type conversion error.

Comment: By the way, had you posted the exact error message, it would have been possible for mere mortals to figure out the problem.

Comment: @SLaks.  The error message is the bible on the head of a pin, and I'm developing on a computer not connected to the internet.

Comment: True; it would be a long message.  _Why_ are you developing on a computer not connected to the internet?

Comment: @SLaks: For security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just get rid of the `Select()` entirely and call `.AsEnumerable()`:

```
return myList.Where(a => a.Group == group)
             .GroupBy(n => n.GroupIndex)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.AsEnumerable());
```

Or you could change your return type to an `ILookup`, which is basically the data structure you're going for:

```
public ILookup<int, MyClass> GetIndexedGroups(string group)
{
    return myList.Where(a => a.Group == group)
                .ToLookup(n => n.GroupIndex);                    
}
```

Comment: The first solution won't help.

Comment: Also, `group` is a contextual keyword.

Comment: @SLaks: Neither will your comment, without more details.

Comment: @Stripling: See my answer for a detailed explanation.  You're still creating a `Dictionary<int, IGrouping<MyClass>>`.

Comment: Thanks.  I used your first example.

Answer (score 5):

Cast `Children` from `IGrouping<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, or explicitly pass generic parameters to the `ToDictionary` call.

The `g` parameter is an `IGrouping<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`.
The implicit generic calls end up creating a `Dictionary<int, IGrouping<MyClass>>`, which cannot be converted to a `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyClass>>`.

This is avoided by your `IndexedGroup` class, since its `Children` property explicitly typed as `IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

<strike>For example:</strike>

```
return myList.Where(a => a.Group == group)
             .GroupBy(n => n.GroupIndex)
             .ToDictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyClass>>(g => g.Key, g => g);
```

Also, you may be interested in the [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx).

Comment: @Robert: You can cast it anywhere.

Comment: Regarding your example, `ToDictionary<T1, T2>` has different (and incompatible) parameter lists than `ToDictionary()`, so your example code won't work.

Comment: @Robert: You're right; I forgot about `TSource`. which is too big to conveniently pass.  Either of the other answers will work fine and be much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
return myList.Where(a => a.Group == group)
             .GroupBy(n => n.GroupIndex)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g as IEnumerable<MyClass>);
```

Comment: I'd prefer calling the .AsEnumerable() method, or changing your ToDictionary signature the way @SLaks does, since it gives you more type safety.